# install from downloaded package

Tags: 12.04, installation

I want to install MySql 5.1 on ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. The reason for MySql 5.1 is that I want to use it with SQLAlchemy (python) which does not support MySql 5.5. If I try to search repository there is only MySql 5.5. I tried `sudo apt-get install mysql-server=5.1.58` but `E: Version ‘5.1.66’ for ‘mysql-server’ was not found` I found package on this page https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.1/5.1.66-0ubuntu0.11.10.2 and downloaded it. I have a problem with installing it.

Is there an option for `apt-get` to read from the directory?

Comment: SQLAlchemy does work with MySQL 5.5. In fact, it's DB API driver which does all the low-level stuff, so SQLAlchemy would work with MySQL 6.0 or 7.0 right now without changes if you have a driver. This link: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/sqlalchemy/ZDiVXW4jqKE - suggest that the issue is either caused by you using the connection in not thread-safe manner or by some obscure bug in the driver. Trying another DB API driver (OurSQL or PyMySQL) makes more sense in the latter case

Comment: I have mySql 5.1 on other machines, so I thought the easiest will be to stay with this version and get it on ubuntu as well especially if it does not cause a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dpkg -i <packagename>
```

is the command to install a downloaded package. See `man dpkg` for more details.